# Unable to switch encoding in GNOME terminal

Tags: terminal, rhel, gnome, character-encoding

In GNOME terminal version: 3.40.3 fro GNOME 40,installed with RHEL 9.1

I Set two kinds of character encodinng and background color in different Profile but only the background changed after switch default to another Profile.

I tried these encodings: Chinese Traditional-Big5,Japanese EUC-JP and Koran EUC-KR but only the UTF-8(default) work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you switch to a profile with a different encoding, can you elaborate on how it does not work as you expect? If you `cat` a file which has the said encoding, does its contents show up properly? For more sophisticated apps to work properly, you have to adjust your locale settings in the shell, did you do that?

Comment: [My personal 2 cents: No one should be using any non-UTF-8 locale or terminal charset anymore. UTF-8 has been the default of pretty much every modern Linux for ~15 years now, everyone should have adapted by now. Many new terminal emulators don't support anything other than UTF-8, and gnome-terminal also _almost_ removed this a few years ago. If you still have data with non-UTF-8 encoding lying around (which you ideally shouldn't, except for ancient backups), you should set the charset in your text viewer / editor app so that it converts to UTF-8 when talking to the terminal.]

Comment: Thanks for replying and advise.I need to maintain some servers with very old databases, due to the application compatibility, all we can do are trying our best to upgrade the OS but keep the same database encoding.  For troubleshooting, I need to switch the encoding in Gnome-Terminal frequently.

Comment: Lately I upgraded my desktop from Centos7 to RockyLinux 9 and set the encoding and background color in some Profile in Gnome-Terminal.I found that switch different Profile can change the background color but nothing changed to the encoding displaying, including  execute bash scripts,cat files,edit file with vi,and so on.The garbled looks the same after switch profile in Gnome-Terminal.

Comment: Btw, I am pretty sure that my locale setting is correct, I still can use another windows desktop with putty to login and display all encoding correctly in the same old server.

Comment: I've tested on my gnome-terminal 3.44 and changing the profile to a different encoding works fine for me. I don't know what could be wrong for you. Note however: "I am pretty sure that my locale setting is correct" - you do have to change the locale settings when you change the encoding, otherwise only simple non-locale-aware tools such as `cat` will work correctly, more complex apps will almost certainly fail. It's not a matter of configuring the locale once, it's about _changing_ it when you change the encoding.